# R: Question about central limit theorem

Tags: r, probability, distributions, self-study, poisson-distribution

Hello everyone :) can you help me please, I really don't understand my teacher's videos and it is the last part of our 20-pages work :O

In question 1 they ask us to create a Poisson distribution and we did this:

```
n <- 1000

lambda <- 1.75

poissonDistribution <- rpois(n, lambda)

hist(poissonDistribution, main="Histogramme Poisson",
     xlab="Nombres de réunion par mois", ylab="Nombre de personnes",
     border="black", col="white", breaks=10)
```

In question 2 they ask us: according to the central limit theorem, what is the probability law $X_{30}$, which has $n = 30$ aleatory variables following a Poisson using $\lambda = 1.75$

We think that the answer is this but we are not sure?

```
n <- 30

lambda <- 1.75

sample <- rpois(n, lambda)

mean(sample)
```

For the third question we really don't understand. It says, using the answer in 2, calculate the probability that $X_{30} > 1.50$. Can you guys help us verifying our answers and finding the third one please :D

Sorry for the english :/ and thank you!!!

Comment: Can you copy the original questions here in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I interpret the exercise (- it may be completely wrong!)

The distribution of a Poisson with lambda = 1.75 is far from a Gaussian:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 1000

lambda <- 1.75

poissonDistribution <- rpois(n, lambda)
hist(poissonDistribution)
```

However, if you average 30 Poissons, each with lambda = 1.75, the distribution is quite close to a normal one:

```
x30 <- matrix(data= NA, nrow= n, ncol= 30)
for(i in 1:ncol(x30)) {
    set.seed(i)
    x30[, i] <- rpois(n, lambda)
}

par(mfrow= c(1, 3))
hist(poissonDistribution)
hist(x30[, i])
hist(rowMeans(x30))
```

[image]

From this simulation, the probability of x > 1.5 is:

```
sum((rowMeans(x30) > 1.5)) / n # 0.827
```

Which is not far from the probability of x > 1.5 in a normal distribution with mean and sd of x30:

```
1 - pnorm(1.5, mean= mean(rowMeans(x30)), sd= sd(rowMeans(x30))) # 0.842
```

(Does it make sense...?)